# Capturing repeated expressions with vim

Tags: search, vim, design-patterns, capture

Following problem in vim:

I want to capture each match of a subpattern in a different match group. An example: for the line:

```
#abcONE# #abcTWO#
```

and the search pattern

```
\(#abc...#\)*
```

I want to obtain the both groups

```
1: #abcONE#   2: #abcTWO#
```

Unfortunately, I obtain only one group, which contains the last recognized subpattern, i.e.

```
#abcTWO#
```

Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only refer to the captured groups directly by number `\1`(and not by range or wildcard), you have to know the number of groups used beforehand, anyway.

Why then not expand the multi item `*` into distinct groups, all matching optionally `\?`:

```
\(#abc...#\)\?\(#abc...#\)\?\(#abc...#\)\?\(#abc...#\)\?
```

Answer (score 0):

what would you do with matched patern? do replace?

```
/#abc...# will select both
:%s/\v(#abc...#)/foo/g will replace both
```

your `\(#abc...#\)*` won't work. becase there is a space between your two "#abc...#"